# OSMDroid memory consumption in offline/online mode

Tags: android, memory-leaks, osmdroid, offline-mode

I'm making app based on the osmdroid sample map viewer (osmdroid-4.3) and I have some performance problems with osm fragment. 
I use unpacked offline MapQuest tiles.

I've noticed this strange memory consumption in offline mode, look at screen please. Memory graph becomes flat after switching to online mode. And logcat spamming all the time in offline about GC stuff.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IowAq.jpg

Also, when I switch it back to offline - nothing happens until I scroll the map, and again this problem appears.

App feels laggy because of this thing. Any advice? Is it normal for osmdroid or I did something wrong?

**============== EDIT ===============**

So I did a short research here and made heap dump. But unfortunately I can understand nothing and hope someone can guide me. 
The MAT said me this things about possible leaks:

Suspect #1 is

```
One instance of "org.osmdroid.views.MapView" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12c7be00" occupies 9,029,024 (17.58%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "org.osmdroid.tileprovider.LRUMapTileCache" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12c7be00".

Keywords
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12c7be00
org.osmdroid.tileprovider.LRUMapTileCache
org.osmdroid.views.MapView
```

Suspect #2

```
One instance of "android.widget.RelativeLayout" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 8,859,712 (17.25%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "org.osmdroid.tileprovider.LRUMapTileCache" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12c7be00".

Keywords
android.widget.RelativeLayout
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12c7be00
org.osmdroid.tileprovider.LRUMapTileCache
```

Suspect #3

```
36 instances of "byte[]", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 9,803,328 (19.09%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:
•byte[1769472] @ 0xa294f000 ................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................... - 1,769,488 (3.45%) bytes. 

Keywords
byte[]
```

I can give any additional information from this dump if needed... All that I understood is - LRUMapTileCache doing useless job in offline mode or something like, but idk how to fix it :/